# How to efficiently split a parsed text & save the left and right part of it

Tags: python, parsing, xpath, lxml, split

So I am parsing some information from the web. Here is the code that does it.

```
import lxml.html
from lxml.etree import XPath

url = "http://gbgfotboll.se/information/?scr=table&ftid=51168"
date = '2014-10-05'

rows_xpath = XPath("//*[@id='content-primary']/table[3]/tbody/tr[td[1]/span/span//text()='%s']" % (date))
time_xpath = XPath("td[1]/span/span//text()[2]")
team_xpath = XPath("td[2]/a/text()")

html = lxml.html.parse(url)

for i,row in enumerate(rows_xpath(html)):
    #time = time_xpath(row)[0].strip()
    team = team_xpath(row)[0]
    print team
```

And prints this:

```
Partille IF FK  - Kode IF
IK Kongahälla - Romelanda UF
etc..
```

Here is the html code of parsed information above(non relevant parts removed):

```
<a href="?scr=result&amp;fmid=2669197">Partille IF FK  - Kode IF</a>
etc..
```

Is there an efficient way of splitting the string while parsing it? The split would occur in "-" so i would save the left part and the right part of it. I would like to save the splitted string in two variables like this:

```
example string: Partille IF FK  - Kode IF
string1 = Partille IF FK
string2 = Kode IF
```

Comment: Maybe try Guava's `StringSplitter`? https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com%2Fgit%2Fjavadoc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fcommon%2Fbase%2FSplitter.html&ei=WT0nVP-6Kc3WigKCqoGwDA&usg=AFQjCNHzx86ZQhw9HamvJpS8y6pK5JlZww&sig2=wEtirp3clr9Ta8G_sFyJuA&bvm=bv.76247554,d.cGE

Comment: +1 why on earth was this downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just split and assign two variables, one for left side and one for the right:

```
s = "Partille IF FK - Kode IF" 
st1, st2 = s.rstrip().split("-") 
st1
Partille IF FK 
st2
Kode IF
```

If you are sure there is only one `-` in each string then the code above will work fine, however if not, you could set `maxsplit` to 1 to split on the first only but whether that would be the correct one to split on is impossible to know without seeing the data:

```
s =  "Partille IF FK  - Kode -IF"
st1, st2 = s.split("-",1)
st1
Partille IF FK   
st2
Kode -IF
```

Comment: Yes i was thinking about that but i thought there might have been a more efficient way while parsing it but ill guess ill use this way

Comment: not sure about lxml but using beautifulSoup you could probably use a regex to split while parsing but I don't know if that would be any more efficient.

Comment: Yea i don't think it would be more efficient. Thanks anyway ill use the code above!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a
'Partille IF FK  - Kode IF'
>>> [i.strip() for i in a.split('-')]
['Partille IF FK', 'Kode IF']
```